# Unity does not work - Segmentation fault

Tags: 11.04, unity, intel-graphics

The Unity interface never appeared on my laptop (Natty - Intel 945GME).

Though, according to the `unity_support_test` script it sould work:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945GME GEM 20100330 DEVELOPMENT x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  1.4 Mesa 7.10.2

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity supported:          yes
```

It is not really a serious problem since I can use Ubuntu Classic, but I would like to know what is wrong in my system.

Now if I try `unity --replace` from Ubuntu Classic, a segmentation error occurs and some problems appear instead of Unity (currently open windows "lose" their title bar,   bottombar tabs are still there but no longer work, etc), so that I must use something like `metacity --replace` to revert to a working state.

Please can someone smart explain me what is wrong, so that I can fix my system and maybe discover what Unity is...

EDIT: I also get a segmentation error with `compiz --replace`.

Here is the output of `unity --replace`:

```
Backend     : gconf
Integration : false
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing scale options...done
Initializing session options...done
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure you have CompizConfig Settings Manager installed and the unity plugin activated as below.

[image]

You can find CCSM in the software centre, just search for compiz

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already had ccsm, so I've checked if the Unity plugin was enabled and retried `unity --replace` but the segmentation error is still there! I've replaced the old output with the new one in my question.

Comment: There is a very good description of what a segmentation fault is on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). I would ensure you have your system up to date and try a restart after enabling the unity plugin in compiz

Comment: I have tried to reboot and starting a ubuntu (Unity) session, it is still perfectly unusable, there is a kind of infinite loop: shortcut icons are visible during roughly half a second, then disappear and appear again... In compiz I had enabled the Unity plugin, and disabled other stuff that was definitely not required by Unity.

Comment: I also get a segmentation error with `compiz --replace`

Comment: @Luc1245 - There is a bug report filed on Launchpad [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/774420) that may be of relevance - are you running a proprietary driver?

Comment: Thank you for your help. However in this bug report, Unity works fine, and crashes only when the user changes something in the Compiz options... In my case Unity never worked at all! I'm using the xorg-video-intel driver. May be I should simply forget Unity and try Unity2D?